# How do I copy color values from one div to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

during the process recreating a game called mastermind I need to copy colorvalues from one div to another when a button is clicked. though i am puzzled on how to do this using javascript. I have browsed the web though I haven't encountered someone with a similar situation. Ill paste the code I have down below so you guys can take a look at it and maybe figure out an efficient way of doing this.

Here is my code:

```js
 var color = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "white", "black", "green", "orange", "magenta"];

 function generateCode() {
   var picked = [];
   while (picked.length < 4) {
     var index = parseInt(Math.random() * color.length, 0);
     var c = color[index];
     if (picked.indexOf(c) == -1) {
       picked.push(c);
     }

   }
   return picked;
 }

 $(function() {
   var pickedCode = generateCode();
   console.log(pickedCode);

   var indices = [];
   $('.pickcolor').on('click', function(e) {
     var index = indices[e.target.id] ? indices[e.target.id] : 0;
     var currentColor = color[index];
     $(e.target).css('background-color', currentColor)
       .data('data-color', currentColor);
     index = index + 1 >= color.length ? 0 : index + 1;
     indices[e.target.id] = index;
   });

   $('#checkButton').on('click', function() {
     var entry = [
       $('#choosecolor0').data('data-color'),
       $('#choosecolor1').data('data-color'),
       $('#choosecolor2').data('data-color'),
       $('#choosecolor3').data('data-color')
     ];

     if (entry.indexOf(undefined) > -1) {
       alert('Je hebt nog geen vier kleuren gekozen');
       return;
     }

   });
 });
```

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 99%;
  width: 99%;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.infobar {
  height: 598px;
  width: 200px;
  right: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 0%;
  background-color: white;
}
.button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 36px;
  top: 11%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}
.turn {
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 0px;
}
.colorpin {
  float: left;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 3px;
}
.spacex {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.colorfield {
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#board {
  width: 652px;
  height: 330px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25.5%;
  left: 25%;
}
#turn-interactive {
  width: 100px;
  height: 357px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 15%
}
.turnint {
  width: 70px;
  height: 265px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  left: 17%;
}
.footer {
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  top: 87%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Master Mind</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<div id="turn-interactiv" class="turnint">
  <div id="choosecolor0" class="spacex pickcolor"></div>
  <div id="choosecolor1" class="spacex pickcolor"></div>
  <div id="choosecolor2" class="spacex pickcolor"></div>
  <div id="choosecolor3" class="spacex pickcolor"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="checkButton" class="button">Check!</button>

<div id="board">
  <div id="turn0" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv0" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space0-0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0-1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0-2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space0-3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn1" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv1" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space1_0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1_1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1_2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space1_3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn2" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv2" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space2-0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space2-1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space2-2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space2-3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn3" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv3" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space3-0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space3-1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space3-2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space3-3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn4" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv4" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space4-0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space4-1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space4-2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space4-3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn5" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv5" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space5_0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space5_1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space5_2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space5_3" class="spacex"></div>

  </div>
  <div id="turn6" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv6" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space6-0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space6-1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space6-2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space6-3" class="spacex"></div>

  </div>
  <div id="turn7" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv7" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space7_0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space7_1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space7_2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space7_3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn8" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv8" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space8_0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space8_1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space8_2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space8_3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="turn9" class="turn">
    <div id="scorediv9" class="spacex">
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
      <div id="colorpin" class="colorpin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="space9_0" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space9_1" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space9_2" class="spacex"></div>
    <div id="space9_3" class="spacex"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<aside>
  <div id="infobar" class="infobar">
    <h1>highscore:</h1>
  </div>`</aside>`
<div id="info" class="footer">
  <footer>
    <p>Jorden Diele</p>
  </footer>
</div>

</body onload="restart()">

</html>
```

What I want to happens is that when I press the "Check!" button, that the colorvalues of the "choosecolor" divs are copied to the "space" divs inside the board, in the order of left to right, in columns and have it check if the first column already contains values, if it does it checks the next one, untill it can copy over the color values to an empty one, making sure turns dont overlap over the first column and leaving the other nine empty.  . The "Check" button also needs to check if the input code corresponds with the comp. generated one. (an array visible inside the console) Though im not quite at that part yet. I have also made it impossible to have two of the same colors in the computer generated code, so if two of the same color are chosen inside the "choosecolor"div I would like to have there be an error message.

Checking the input code and having the black and white pins appear correspondingly (if you know mastermind works you'll know what I mean) is going to be a whole nother problem in and of it self, but that will have to wait for another question ;).

Kudos and a lot of thanks to everyone,
Yours sincerely, A programming noob :)

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this ?

Comment: provide minimal example

Comment: The biggest problem staring out at us, is the fact that element `id`s need to be unique. Having all those elements with `id='colorpin'` is invalid. However, that said - you can either grab the value directly, as stated in an answer, or in some cases, you'll need to rely upon `window.getComputedStyle`, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Not read this in depth, but purely from the title, would something like this be what you're after? `$("#a").css("background-color", $("#b").css("background-color"))` Literally assigning the colour of one (b) to the other (a)?

Comment: @JordenDiele A "Fiddle" refers to a snippet from https://jsfiddle.net/ which displays a small amount of functional code. It lets people have a play with the code and make it easier to look through (And lets us see the problem for ourselves)

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript, you can easily get the color value :

```
alert(myDiv.style.backgroundColor);
```

Comment: If wanted to just give it a color value then I would have done so in CSS. The problem I'm having is to copy the colors chosen by the player during the game for the four "choosecolor" divs to the ones on the boards. The computer needs to give them a color for me when the button is clicked, rather than me just giving everything a class with a color. Thanks for giving it some though though.